# How to make libpcap be found by pkg-config

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, libpcap, pkg-config

I'm trying to adjust the dependencies of a software that requires `libpcap` to be installed, but for some reason it cannot find it.

This software uses `pkg-config` to try to find the dependency `libpcap`, and I can see `libpcap-dev` is installed, and so does `libpcap0.8`:

**dpkg -s libpcap-dev:**

```
Package: libpcap-dev
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: libdevel
Installed-Size: 34
Maintainer: Romain Francoise <rfrancoise@debian.org>
Architecture: armhf
Multi-Arch: same
Source: libpcap
Version: 1.8.1-6
Depends: libpcap0.8-dev
```

**dpkg -s libpcap0.8**

```
Package: libpcap0.8
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 286
Maintainer: Romain Francoise <rfrancoise@debian.org>
Architecture: armhf
Multi-Arch: same
Source: libpcap
Version: 1.8.1-6
Replaces: libpcap0.8-dev (<< 1.0.0-2)
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.11)
```

I also can see the shared library exists `ldconfig -p | grep libpcap`:

```
    libpcap.so.0.8 (libc6,hard-float) => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpcap.so.0.8
    libpcap.so (libc6,hard-float) => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpcap.so
```

But `pkg-config --modversion libpcap` still cant find it. I also looked up all `$PKG_DIR_PATH` available, none of them has a `libpcap.pc` config file.

This is what I'm trying to build: https://github.com/martinpitt/umockdev

I have no idea on how can I inform `pkg-config` about the existence of `libpcap`.

Comment: What does `pkg-config --list-all | grep pcap` print?

Comment: "I also looked up all `$PKG_DIR_PATH` available"  Is there a `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf` directory?  If so, is there a `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig` directory?  If so, does it include a `libpcap.pc` file?

Comment: There were no `libpcap.pc` files on ANY of the directories listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The libpcap on your system is based on the tcpdump.org libpcap 1.8.1 release.  That release did not provide .pc files, and Debian didn't bother providing them itself.

.pc files were added in libpcap 1.9, so 1.9.0, and all later releases, including the current 1.10.1 release, provide .pc files.

You will either need to:

1. upgrade the OS on your machine to something that provides a 1.9 or 1.10 libpcap release;
2. download and install libpcap 1.10.1 yourself;
3. change umockdev to use the pcap-config script if it's present and no .pc files are present.